# Regex to remove Wiki Markup?

Tags: c#, regex, wiki, markup

I'm trying to remove all Wiki markup from some text. I want to process the text but all the markup is messing it up. Do you know how to remove all the markup?

If regex isn't viable, I am using C#.

Example text: http://regexr.com/39fnb

Edit: I've come up with the following regex: ([[)|(]])|(Category:.*)|({{.*}})|(=+.+=)|([.*?])

It works at parsing some stuff, but not everything. For example, it can't parse the lines starting with | that have code. I tried adding something that could do that, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please make sure to scope down your question so it is not so inviting to close as duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) ... Consider using search engine to help to narrow down the request - like http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+parser+Wiki+markup

Comment: Try to accomplish it yourself first, and when you come across a more specific (**concrete**) problem, post it here, showing what you've tried and what you're struggling with.

Comment: few lines of input output can be added

Comment: What did you try for parsing lines beginning with `|`?

Comment: @Gutblender I think it was Something like (^[ ]?|) I'm not sure why it didn't work. I added a | between that and the rest. It works in the online checker, but it doesn't work in the program.

Comment: In regex, to match characters not in a set, you use `[^chars]`, not `^[chars]`.

Comment: @Gutblender It removed my space, but ther was a space between the [].

It worked in the web emulator, and also in a .net regex emulator. What would you suggest to fix it?